# Why is ForeignKey_Edit loading primary key as the value, instead of the actual value used in the association?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm using ASP.NET dynamic data to create a ticket edit form.  The Ticket is associated to a problem code, but not using the problem code's primary key.  (The database is 3rd party, so I don't have control over that...)

So the problemCode looks basically like:

```
ProblemCode
(
    ID int,
    Code varchar(8),
    Description varchar(250)
)
```

The association is between Ticket.ProblemCode and ProblemCode.Code

Now the problem is that ForeignKey_Edit (really, PopulateListControl) fills the dropdown with the Primary Key which is ID... but the ticket is actually using Code to tie the two together.  Am I missing something?  Is there a simple way to get it to use Code as the value instead?

If not I can probably eliminate ID from the view as I don't think it HAS to be used anywhere... I just like having an ID around.

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?  Did the foreign key relationship from the DB get pulled into your "DataContext" correclty?

Comment: Linq to SQL, and I manually set up the foreign key relationship because it's based on views.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your metadata:

```
[DisplayColumn("Code")] 
public partial class ProblemCode{ }
```